# Is order of redshift interleaved sort keys important?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is it important for the where clause to specify interleaved  sort keys in the same order as they are defined? I would think it is. If the order is important, why cant the query planner figure this out itself?

Answer (score 1):

I think the order doesn't matter.

In chapter "[Comparing Sort Styles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Sorting_data-compare-sort-styles.html)", I have found some interesting benchmark.

Table's scheme:

```
create table cust_sales_date_interleaved as
(select c_custkey, c_nation, c_region, c_mktsegment, d_date::date, lo_revenue
from customer, lineorder, dwdate
where lo_custkey = c_custkey 
and lo_orderdate = dwdate.d_datekey
and lo_revenue > 0)
interleaved sortkey (c_custkey, c_region, c_mktsegment, d_date);
```

query #1

```
select max(lo_revenue), min(lo_revenue)
from cust_sales_date_interleaved
where c_region = 'ASIA'
and c_mktsegment = 'FURNITURE';
```

query #2

```
select max(lo_revenue), min(lo_revenue)
from cust_sales_date_interleaved
where d_date between '01/01/1996' and '01/14/1996'
and c_mktsegment = 'FURNITURE'
and c_region = 'ASIA';
```

And we have results

query #1 - **1.46 s**

query #2 - **0.80 s**

Query #2 is faster because it has extra filter by `d_date`.

Comment: Good find from the documentation. Thanks. Will validate the results.